# Extract GUID from line via regular expression in perl

Tags: regex, perl, expression, guid

I have problems testing for and when successful extracting a GUID from a line of a textfile. Given a guid 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc, where all hexadecimal characters are allowed (I use digits and abc to display the number of characters each substring contains), I tried it like this

```
my $myline = "  set whatevervariable = \'aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-1234-aaaaaaaabbbb\'";
my $guid =($myline =~ m/[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-]([A-Fa-f0-9]){12}/gi)
```

The test works fine, but how can I extract the GUID afterwards and use it as a string in my perl script? The [] operator does not work...

Thanks for help,
G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use group:

```
my $guid =($myline =~ m/([A-Fa-f0-9]{8}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-]([A-Fa-f0-9]){12})/gi)
# note parens    here __^                                                                      and         here __^
```

You could also simplify the regex:

```
my $guid =($myline =~ m/([a-f\d]{8}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-([a-f\d]){12})/gi)
```

According to daxim's comment, you'd add `a` modifier:

```
my $guid =($myline =~ m/([a-f\d]{8}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-([a-f\d]){12})/gia)
```

or use

```
my $guid =($myline =~ m/([[:xdigit:]]{8}-[[:xdigit:]]{4}-[[:xdigit:]]{4}-[[:xdigit:]]{4}-([[:xdigit:]]){12})/gia)
```

Comment: Ah, that works perfectly well! Thanks for the grouping hint! G.

Comment: The simplification is wrong. [\d matches more than just 0-9.](http://p3rl.org/perlrecharclass#Digit) [Use :xdigit: instead.](http://p3rl.org/perlrecharclass#POSIX-Character-Classes)

Comment: @daxim: You're right, editing answer accordingly. But it works depending on locale.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $myline = "  set whatevervariable = \'aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-1234-aaaaaaaabbbb\'";                                 
my ($guid) =($myline =~ m/([A-Fa-f0-9]{8}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{12})/gi);
```

There are two changes:

1. you had your parens wrong.
2. when you do: `$variable = $some_other =~ m/.../g; - the $variable will contain number of matches. If you want the match, you should do:`my ( $variable ) = ...`. If there is a change of actually having more than one guid in the file, use: my @guids = $myline =~ m/..../g;

Additionally - since you are using //i flag, there is no need to use [A-Fa-f] - simple [a-f] is good enough. What's more - you don't have to do [-] thing. - character is not magical in regexps.

This all sums to:

```
my @guids = $myline =~ m/([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12})/gi;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I already deleted the upper case characters from the regexp...